# Changing JSON object formatting

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I get the following JSON object response from the server

```
{"query":"hi",
 "suggestions":["history","hilton","hilton hhonors","hillary clinton", "hickory farms","hip2save","hitler","hipaa"]
}
```

and I want to convert it into this type of JSON format using PHP:

```
["hi",["history","higheredjobs","hilton","hillary clinton","hitler","hip2save","hindustan times","hipaa"]]
```

I feel like I might be confused about the second format. Is that a valid type of JSON object?

Thanks for your help in advance for looking into this.

Comment: _"into this type of JSON format using PHP"_ do you mean you want it so that the _"response from the server"_ is in your second format? Or that your php code is making some kind of request to some place and you need to do this all in php? If so where does the javascript come in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your server you presumably have an array that looks like this:

```
array(
   'query' => 'hi',
   'suggestions' => 
  array (
    0 => 'history',
    1 => 'hilton',
    2 => 'hilton hhonors',
    3 => 'hillary clinton',
    4 => 'hickory farms',
    5 => 'hip2save',
    6 => 'hitler',
    7 => 'hipaa',
  ),
)
```

and you then

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

which gives you the JSON you are currently receiving. To change that to the format you desire, use [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the input array to remove the associative keys and then `json_encode` it:

```
$array = array_values($array);
echo json_encode($array);
```

This will give you output in the format you desire, which is indeed valid JSON:

```
["hi",
 ["history","higheredjobs","hilton","hillary clinton","hitler","hip2save","hindustan times","hipaa"]
]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/q3Vfu)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!! Thank you for making my life a lot easier :) you're the best

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [**`Object.values()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

> The [**`Object.values()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```js
var data = {"query":"hi","suggestions":["history","hilton","hilton hhonors","hillary clinton","hickory farms","hip2save","hitler","hipaa"]}

var res = Object.values(data);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This also worked for me, but Nick's answer allowed me to keep everything in PHP. Thanks for your input though, I'm sure someone else will find it useful